# Software to compare two folders recursively

Tags: windows, comparison, directories, file

I am going to reorganise a lot of files and I do not want any files to go missing. I am using Windows. Is there a way I can compare two folders recursively?

For example, folder 1

```
MyFiles/
    ├─ folder1
    │  ├─ file1
    │  ├─ file2
    │  ├─ file3
    │  ├─ file4
```

and it has hundreds of files.

The files will be reorganized based on date so the new folder structure looks like this,

```
MyFiles/
    ├─ folder2
    │  ├─ 2022
    |  │  ├─ file1
    |  │  ├─ file2
    │  ├─ 2023
    |  │  ├─ file3
    |  │  ├─ file4
```

I want to list the missing files only from both folders.

I have tried Multi-Commander but I have not been able to achieve this as it does not look into subfolders.

A GUI tool or a bat file will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  I took a look to see if the folder comparison tool integrated into [WinMerge](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge) could do what you want, but I did not see the required functionality.  You may want to ask on the [WinMerge Discussion area on GitHub](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/discussions) to see if WinMerge can do this automatically.

If not, may I recommend dropping down to a command prompt and using the `dir` command in conjunction with [WinMerge](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge)?

By issuing the command `dir /a-d /s | sort /+37 /o allfiles.txt` you will generate a text file named `allfiles.txt` that contains the name of every file within the current directory tree.

Run that command in `folder1` and `folder2` (using your example).

You can then use [Winmerge](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge) to compare those output text files to quickly find any files you missed (simply ignore the blank lines and directory names at the top of the comparison).

Please note, depending on the locale of the system you are using, you may need to slightly modify the value of the `/+` parameter for the `sort` command (to which the output of `dir` is being piped).  For this use, that parameter specifies the first character of each filename generated by the `dir` command.

Comment: As you mentioned there is no direct way of doing this I did try WinMerge but could not figure it out. I am currently using dupeGuru (suggested by chatGPT) to find duplicates in the two folders. So what it does is it lists all the duplicates found in both folders, I can see there are 20 duplicate files and if the file number in each folder is different then I know some files are missing.

Comment: Glad you tried WinMerge too.  Yes, similar to dupeGuru, you can use NirSoft's SearchMyFiles (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html) to find duplicates.  The difficultly with duplicate file finders is that they won't tell you which files are missing in your new folder structure... unless, of course, they are specifically designed to do so.

Comment: There is this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSvdQL8x5Zc where the problem is solved. But it uses a paid software called beyondCompare. This is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: Meld is a tool that shows the list of files that are present and missing files as well. But when clicking on a specific file to compare it freezes. So it is buggy.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning beyondCompare and Meld.  I'm surprised Meld is crashing because it has been around for many years.  Maybe you can report the crash to its dev team so they can fix it?